# Using a 3 d list in python to store and modify count of an element based on its occurence

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a file containing hexadecimal data, in the format **55 12 3d 4e aa etc**, in each line. I have a list of unique lengths obtained from scanning the entire file. Also, I am getting the count of these unique length by scanning the entire file. For example:

```
Line 1: 55,76,2e,44,12,54,aa,76,23,3e

Line 2: 76,2e,44,54,76,23

Line 3: 55,23,65,78,90,e4,aa,67

and so on

My expected output after including the below mentioned process will appear something like:

 Length - 10 Count - 20000
          EscLength - 2 Count - 10000
          EscLength - 7 Count - 8000 

 Length - 4 Count - 5000
          EscLength - 5 Count - 3000
          EscLength - 7 Count - 2000
```

The original data contains "Escape contents". I have an algorithm to detect them and get the length of the updated data. Now, I have to find the unique length of the escape contents for each unique original lengths and then get the count of each escape content corresponding the unique lengths of the original data.

I tried to build a 3 d list in python that will contain **[original length, length of escape content, count of the length of escape content]**. I could not update the count. It is kind of getting complicated when i find the unique values and the update/insert counts.

```
for i in xrange(len(escCount_list)):
     strspl = str(escCount_list[i]).split(',')
     for strs in strspl:
          if(strs == len(packet_list)-len(afterEsc_list) and strspl[0] == len(packet_list)):
                 escCount_list[i].append(len(packet_list)
                 escCount_list[i].append(len(packet_list)-len(afterEsc_list))
                 storeCount = escCount_list[i]
                 escCount_list[i].append(storeCount + 1)
          if(strspl[0] == len(packet_list)):
                 escCount_list[i].append(len(packet_list)
                 escCount_list[i].append(len(packet_list)-len(afterEsc_list))
                 storeCount = escCount_list[i]
                 escCount_list[i].append(storeCount + 1)
```

When I encounter a new length, I try to include the values like this:

```
escCount_list[rows].append(len(packet_list)-len(afterEsc_list))
escCount_list[rows].append(len(packet_list))
escCount_list[rows].append(1)
rows = rows + 1
cols = cols + 1
```

It looks like I have made my script very messy. I had to address loads of issues and I am doing everything on one script because of the requirement I have. Is there a way to modify this or use an easy way to solve this problem. *PS:* Currently I am getting list index out of bound exception at **escCount_list[rows].append()** line.